# Transform button on hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to achieve an effect in html and css. I have a button which says "Login". So what I'm trying to do is when I hover:

The login button transforms into two buttons which says:

"Customer Login" and "Admin Login".

Comment: Can you show us some code that you've done so far please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to make it with some simple css;

```css
.login-actions { position: relative; }
.login-actions a { display: inline-block; padding: 1rem 2rem; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; background: #111; }
.login-actions a:not(:first-child) { opacity: 0; }
.login-actions:hover a:not(:first-child) { opacity: 1; }
.login-actions:hover a:first-child { opacity: 0; position: absolute; left:0; top: 0; z-index: -1; }
```

```html
<div class="login-actions">
  <a href="#">Login</a>
  <a href="#">Customer Login</a>
  <a href="#">Admin Login</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery we can do the check below example

```js
$(".hide").hide();
$(".hoverHide").mouseover(function(){
$(".hoverHide").hide();
$(".hide").show();
});

$(".hoverHide").mouseleave(function(){
$(".hoverHide").show();
$(".hide").hide();
});
```

```css
.login {
width:300px;
padding: 10px;
background: #ccc;
}

.login button {display:inline-block;margin: 5px 4px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="login">
<p>Login</p>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="password"/><br>
<button class="hoverHide">Login</button>
<div class="hide"><button>Customer Login</button> <button>Admin Login</button></div>
</div>
```